# Gradle: MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'com' on LibraryVariantImpl

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In an Android project I want to update the Gradle plug-in from `0.9.+` to `0.10.4`.
However, the following error occurs:

```
MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'com' on 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.LibraryVariantImpl_Decorated@2ba15f02.
```

The error occurs at the `if` clause:

```
// build.gradle

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    if (name.equals(com.android.builder.BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
    }

    // ...
}
```

I cannot see the problem since [the `DEBUG` constant seems to be `public`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/BuilderConstants.java).
A dirty fix to get it running would be:

```
// build.gradle

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    if (name.equals("debug")) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
    }

    // ...
}
```

The full project can be found [here](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/TypedPreferences), branch: `feature/update-project`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of `BuilderConstants` moved, but not in 0.10.X of the plugin -- it was in 0.11. Regardless, try this:

```
import com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants
```

There's a brief discussion of the issue here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/A9e-78LVz8E

Answer (score 1):

Don't know but seems that gradle has problems with correct resolution. Try to import `BuilderConstants` at the beginning of the script:

```
import com.android.builder.BuilderConstants
```

And then use it in this way:

```
if (name.equals(BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
}
```

Comment: Adding the import seems to be not working: `unable to resolve class com.android.builder.BuilderConstants ...`

Comment: Do You have script dependencies configured? I guess there's something missing. Any minimal working example?

Comment: I added the link to the Android library project. The branch `feature/update-project` contains the unfinished Gradle update.

Comment: Try Scott Barta's response.